# Unity webGL keeps centring on page height

Tags: html, css, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I've imported my Unity game to WebGL but the game window keeps centering to the height of the page, changing its positioning and overlapping other parts of the page, and I cannot figure out why. I'm not sure if it is a default setting or something I have accidentally turned on but any help would be appreciated thank you.
This is the code for the game on said page:

```
<div id="unity-container" class="unity-desktop">
          <canvas id="unity-canvas"></canvas>
          <div id="unity-loading-bar">
            <div id="unity-logo"></div>
            <div id="unity-progress-bar-empty">
              <div id="unity-progress-bar-full"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script>
          var buildUrl = "Build";
          var loaderUrl = buildUrl + "/TEST.loader.js";
          var config = {
            dataUrl: buildUrl + "/TEST.data.gz",
            frameworkUrl: buildUrl + "/TEST.framework.js.gz",
            codeUrl: buildUrl + "/TEST.wasm.gz",
            streamingAssetsUrl: "StreamingAssets",
            companyName: "Sam and Jake",
            productName: "Space Terminal Zero",
            productVersion: "0.99",
          };

          var container = document.querySelector("#unity-container");
          var canvas = document.querySelector("#unity-canvas");
          var loadingBar = document.querySelector("#unity-loading-bar");
          var progressBarFull = document.querySelector("#unity-progress-bar-full");
          var fullscreenButton = document.querySelector("#unity-fullscreen-button");

          if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            container.className = "unity-mobile";
            config.devicePixelRatio = 1;
          } else {
            canvas.style.width = "960px";
            canvas.style.height = "600px";
          }
          loadingBar.style.display = "block";

          var script = document.createElement("script");
          script.src = loaderUrl;
          script.onload = () => {
            createUnityInstance(canvas, config, (progress) => {
              progressBarFull.style.width = 100 * progress + "%";
            }).then((unityInstance) => {
              loadingBar.style.display = "none";
              fullscreenButton.onclick = () => {
                unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);
              };
            }).catch((message) => {
              alert(message);
            });
          };
          document.body.appendChild(script);
        </script>
```

And this is the CSS I have added manually:

```
.unity-desktop {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin-top: 325px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 50px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

Again any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: This is a css issue not a unity issue. Check the css for those divisions

Comment: Found a style sheet buried in files that was adjusting it but sorted it now thanks!